# Bootstrap 3.2.0 glyphicons not showing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I'm trying to show glyphicons within my textbox.

This is the markup I have:

```
 <div class="form-group" style="width: 100%;" id="divFirstName" runat="server">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" runat="server" id="txtFirstName" value="" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status" class="form-control" maxlength="30" />
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span id="inputSuccess2Status" class="sr-only">(success)</span>
                                    </div>
```

And this is the result I'm getting:

[image]

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: how were you loading your files initially? from your server? or using cdn links?

Comment: From my server, bootstrap version 3.2.0

Comment: then my believe is: you accepted the wrong answer. if you want to keep using your bootstrap version 3.2.0 from your server you need to modify your css so it points to the right file. It doesn't matter what version you are running. updating it, doesn't have much effects on the glyphicons except they get updated which is not that often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to include the **latest** bootstrap css styles.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Also make sure that you are not overriding the `font-family` property of the icon `span` somewhere in your CSS.

Comment: @wazaaap I have the bootstrap min css included

Comment: Yeah, but he shouldn't be getting that style for the input box if he was using bootstrap, check the updated answer.

Comment: @wazaaap using the latest version fixed my problem. I'll mark your answer as correct shortly, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine for me. Are you including the most recent bootstrap CSS (3.3.5 currently)?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Also, you have to add the class `has-feedback` to the form group container.

Here is a fiddle showing it working: https://jsfiddle.net/dnje3g1y/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="form-group has-feedback" style="width: 100%;" id="divFirstName" runat="server">

<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" runat="server" id="txtFirstName" value="" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status" class="form-control" maxlength="30" />
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span id="inputSuccess2Status" class="sr-only">(success)</span>

</div>
```

Comment: Updated to be more of an 'answer'

Answer (score 1):

Since you were loading the files from your local server and they were not working, the problem came from the way your font files and css files were set us. The css from bootstrap looks for the fonts one folder upwards (the parent directory of current directory the file is in).

This is the set up of bootstrap files. According to the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/).

```
bootstrap/
├── css/
│   ├── bootstrap.css
│   ├── bootstrap.css.map
│   ├── bootstrap.min.css
├── js/
│   ├── bootstrap.js
│   └── bootstrap.min.js
└── fonts/
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
    └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

if your files are not set up this way, you can modify the css files to point to the path of your font files

Comment: Thats how I had the structure

Comment: you code works super fine in bootply and jsfiddle then check for 404 error in your console.  @laziale

Comment: Had the `fonts` folder missing and downloaded it from the Bootstrap site (full source code), fixed it